# Printing bash command line args with $@ inline

Tags: bash, echo, verbosity

I want to add verbosity to my bash function by printing the command that it will run. What is the best way to print all arguments `$@` inline?

```bash
ggtest ()
{
    echo 'git grep -n $@ -- "src/tests/*"'

    git grep -n "$@" -- "src/tests/*";
}
```

So that I can see an output such as:

```bash
$ ggtest "models and views"
git grep -n "models and views" -- "src/tests/*"
...
```

Comment: Variant 1 (cheapest): Turn on tracing with `set -x` before you execute your command. Don't forget to turn it off afterwards (`set +x`). Version 2 (elegant): Create an array holding the grep command with all arguments. Print the array in any formatting you like. Execute the array.

Comment: Putting `$@` in a string splits the string up into multiple words. For example if you run `set -- "first word" "second word" "third word"`, then `echo "prefix${@}suffix"` will run `echo "prefixfirst word" "second word" "third wordsuffix"` -- but of course, `echo`'s output doesn't show you where its argument separators were, so the location of those quotes is lost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An overcomplicated version you can cut down to support only the specific shell releases you need support for:

```
ggtest ()
{
    # note the following explicitly exits if run in a shell w/o array support
    local -a cmd || return                    # declare a function-local array
    cmd=( git grep -n "$@" -- "src/tests/*" ) # store intended command in array

    # below here, we take a different approach based on running bash version
    case $BASH_VERSION in

      '') # no BASH_VERSION == we're running with a shell that's not bash at all
        set -x                                # enable trace logging
        : "${cmd[@]}"                         # run : with our array as arguments
        { set +x; } 2>/dev/null               # silently disable tracing
        ;;

      [1-4].*) # pre-5.0 bash does not support ${var@Q}; these logs are uglier
        { printf '%q ' "${cmd[@]}"; printf \n; } >&2 ;;

      *) # modern bash; shortest syntax, prettiest output
        printf '%s\n' "${cmd[*]@Q}" >&2;;
    esac
    "${cmd[@]}"                               # execute our array
}
```

Note that in current shell releases `printf %q` will use backslashes rather than quotes for escaping, so it would change `ggtest "some string"` to have `some\ string` in the logs; not the worst thing in the word, but it's less pretty than `${array[*]@Q}`'s representation